# problem with \ref getting ?? Texshop 4.74 4.77

Tags: cross-referencing, texshop, equation-number

I have a mac desktop running TexShop 4.74 and a macbook air M1 running 4.77. When I run a document (created on the former and running PERFECTLY) but over on the latter, any \ref to a tagged equation and comes up with ??. The message is "\ref `V' undefined in line 32."
It is a \documentclass{book} with \input{chapter1} \input{chapter2} etc.
Tried same with a (different) \documentclass{article} and all was fine.
Having same issue with \cite but I'll fry that fish next - maybe same problem?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805)

Comment: just to be sure: do you know about double compilation of LaTeX and why you need one?

Comment: make a small but complete example that we can test and that demonstrates the error.

Comment: \textbf{Vi\`ete's Product} is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2}{\pi}\,=\,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}{2_{_{_{_{_{_{}}}}}}} \, \cdot \cdots .
\tag{V} \label{V}
\end{equation}
\textbf{$\bullet$}\,Proof of (\ref{V})
\\
Following \cite{Maor}, for example, we begin with a preliminary infinite product, discovered by Euler:

Comment: ... this comes out with ?? for the reference to the equation and [?] for the citation.

Comment: Anton- yes I do thanks.

Comment: I removed 4.77 from my MacBook Air, installed 4.74 and the problems have disappeared. Not entirely satisfactory, but I am all set. Thanks to anyone who noodled with this - even a little.